# How to create and display a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a grid in PHP and display a value in selected cell whose value matching with database cell value.

Grid example:

```
A1|B1|C1|D1|E1|F1|G1|H1|
A2|B2|C2|D2|E2|F2|G2|H2|
A3|B3|C3|D3|E3|F3|G3|H3|
```

In database I have a column named `cell_address` that contain values like `[A1,A2,D3,H3]`;

How can I put the database value within the grid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$cell_address = "[A1,A2,D3,H3]";

$ar_columns = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H');
$ar_rows = array('1', '2', '3');

$ar_addresses = explode(",", substr($cell_address, 1, -1));

$html = "<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>".implode("</td><td>", $ar_columns)."</th>
  </tr>\n";

foreach($ar_rows as $row)
{
  $html .= "<tr><th>".$row."</th>\n";

  foreach($ar_columns as $col)
  {
    $cell_str = (in_array($col.$row, $ar_addresses) ? "match" : "&nbsp;");
    $html .= "<td>".$cell_str."</td>\n";
  }

  $html .= "</tr>\n";
}

$html .= "</table>\n";

echo $html;
```

Comment: its a good idea. thank you very much. i hv already done it but you hv smart idea and i ll change ur idea with my ...

Answer (score 0):

Simply fetch the data from database using mysql_fetch_array() and display it in the grid ...

Answer (score 0):

For questions like this I can only say: read the manual (e.g. [this](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) which also contains examples) and study the language basics